# Rake data import task isn't updating correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, import, rake-task

I have a .txt file full of attributes like so:

```
"12345", "1", "Kent"
"67890", "1", "New Castle"
```

I need this to update my County model, and so I have this rake task:

```
namespace :data do
  desc "import data from files to database"
  task :import => :environment do
    file = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "tasks", "counties.txt"), "r")
    file.each do |line|
      attrs = line.split(", ")
      c = County.find_or_initialize_by_number(attrs[0])
      c.state_id = attrs[1]
      c.name = attrs[2]
      c.save!
    end
  end
end
```

All seems to be well, but when I check in the console to make sure it was imported correctly, I get this:

```
#<County id: 2, name: nil, number: 0, state_id: 0, created_at: "2013-08-04 17:44:11", updated_at: "2013-08-04 17:44:11">
```

I know that it's actually importing something, because it has created exactly the right number of County records, but it's not actually updating the attributes correctly. I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious but I can't find it!

Comment: Have you tried doing these steps in the console?

Comment: Do you have any callbacks after_save or something similar?

Comment: Just discovered something: when I change the data to read like this instead: 54109, 5, "Wyoming" i.e., remove the quotes around the integers, then it will update. So my problem is that it's reading the quotes and then not updating the integer fields. Is there a better way to write line.split?

Comment: No callbacks after_save, what steps do you mean in the console? I've been checking using County.find(1) to see how it updates. So far when I remove the quotes around the middle number (state_id), it updates the appropriate column, but the same thing won't work for the first number (number). I'm not sure why it's being so fickle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumption: County.number is defined as an integer field.

attrs[0] after your line.split comes out to be "\"12345\"" (a string). The find_by method defaults the lookup key to 0 (integer) given that it's looking up an integer field (number). This would explain why your code works when you manually strip out the quotation marks from the first data column in the text file.

Based on this root cause, there could be multiple ways to resolve your issue. Here's an ugly way:

```
c = County.find_or_initialize_by_number(Integer(attrs[0].gsub(/\"/, '')))
```

Ideally, I would trim out (or gsub) quotes when doing the line text split.

Comment: County.number is an integer, as well as state_id. But for some reason, stripping out the quotes only worked once. It worked when I stripped it out around the second data column from the last line on the text file, but will not work when removed from the first column.

Comment: Also, when I remove all of the quotes from the text file, nothing happens at all.

Comment: I still don't know why it didn't work in this instance, but I ended up removing my County model and creating it again, and then ran the rake task with all the quotes removed. Worked fine!